# replacing the column between 2 columns that have different column name using sql

Tags: sql, join, merge

How can I replace the content of home_team_api_id and away_team_id to real name
I have 2 tables using sql. first one is the home and away id and the 2nd one is the description of the home and away id from table 1

Table 1

```
home_team_api_id    away_team_api_id
================    ================
8600                8540
9882                8636
8524                8551
8529                8543
8530                10233
```

Table 2

```
team_api_id       team_long_name     team_short_name
===========       ==============     ===============
8600                Udinese          UDI
9882                Sampdoria        SAM
8524                Atalanta         ATA
8529                Cagliari         CAG
8530                Catania          CAT
8540                Palermo          PAL
8636                Inter            INT
8551                Siena            SIE
8543                Lazio            LAZ
10233               Genoa            GEN
```

desired result

```
home_team_api_id    away_team_api_id
================    ================
Udinese              Palermo          
Sampdoria            Inter            
Atalanta             Siena            
Cagliari             Lazio            
Catania              Genoa
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `table2` twice with different alias names

```
select home.team_long_name as home_team_api_id,
       away.team_long_name as away_team_api_id
from table1
join table2 as home on home.team_api_id = table1.home_team_api_id
join table2 as away on away.team_api_id = table1.away_team_api_id
```